# Does the browser invert the height and width when the phone is in landscape mode?

Tags: css, height, width, landscape, portrait

I tried to find the answer yesterday searching on internet, but found nothing. How does the browser handle the height and width when we rotate the phone? For example: if we have an header of 100vh, in portrait mode is quite high. But when we rotate the phone, so landscape mode, do those 100vh apply to what it was the width in portrait mode?
How should we handle this in media queries? Should we set one that says "when in landscape mode make the header with a fix heigth instead of using vh"?
Thanks for your answers and thanks for your help:)

Comment: _do those 100vh apply to what it was the width in portrait mode?_ it's the new height in landscape mode. 
You could also use `100vmax` and/or a `min-height`

Comment: You can also use media queries to determine what way the phone is being held `@media (orientation: portrait) {...}`